# QuickSight: How can I use ifelse() or any other alternative for multiple conditions according to input provided in the added parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I get the option of `ifelse()` in the Functions list when I am trying to add a calculated field while editing the data, but do not get it from the 'Add' option where I get the option to Add title, Add description, Add calculated field, Add parameter. I get options like sumif, avgif, countif but there I can provide only one condition.
I want to create an `ifelse(0)` function with multiple conditions dependent on a parameter value which user selects from a dropdown.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Are you asking for help on how to create an ifelse() with multiple conditions...?  If so, please update your question's title because it's not a question.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to add ifelse() function you have to add it at the Dataset section. it is  not available in Data analysis section.
- If you want to add multiple choice values in the parameter, then you have to add the list of items by

  - click on Add Parameter
  - in the "Create new parameter" dialogue box, select multiple values then write the list of items by each line in the below text area.
  - then click on the create.

Answer (score 0):

Currently IfEsle() is not supported in analysis based on SPICE dataset. If you want to use IfElse() in analysis convert SPICE dataset to a Direct Query dataset.